# How to fetch data with paging

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

How can I get ALL data if API has a pager? how can I do this on ruby on rails?

```
eg. http://website/activity?page1&per_page=50
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Set `per_page` to 1000000 :)

Comment: what are you using for pagination?

Comment: Can you help me understand how this is a real question? Is YOUR application the API? Or are you consuming an API that pages results?

Comment: I'm trying to consume an API's pages results. Because it has the maximum of 50 per page